# How to run a Python file as argument for a C file?

Tags: python, c

The C file takes exactly one argument

This is what I did in terminal:

```
vim abc.py
```

In `abc.py` I wrote:

```
padding = "AAAA"
print padding
```

I saved it so when I did `ls` in terminal, I see that `abc.py` exists.

I ran the program like this:

```
./overflow < abc.py
```

It didn't work. 
So I also tried:

```
python abc.py > alpha
./overflow < /home/alpha
```

It didn't work, it said "no such file"

How can I use the content inside the Python script as argument for the C file?

Comment: what does your c program do?

Comment: @nilsocket, how is that relevant?

Comment: it calls another function called zerg that checks the length of the argument with strlen.

Comment: Maybe try `./overflow $(python abc.py)`

Comment: Maybe you need a [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) but I don't guess what you actually want. Your question is *really* unclear

Answer (score 1):

If your C program can take input from STDIN you can simply pipe the output of your Python program into your C program:

```
python abc.py | ./overflow
```

If you need to pass the output of `abc.py` literally on the command line you can use [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

```
python abc.py | xargs ./overflow
```

This answer assumes that you're on some kind of POSIX operating system. If you're not, or if you're using a very strange shell, it may need adjustment.

Comment: `./overflow "$(python abc.py)"` would also work on `bash` and `zsh` (probably others) assuming it didn't produce so many arguments that it exceeded the command line length limit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes, that would work in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming that you want to call your python script from your C file?
Have you tried using system calls?
You can try using this too :-

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


FILE* file;



Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
file = fopen("abc.py","r");
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "abc.py");
Py_Finalize();

return;
}
```